# I don't understand why we need an argument when calling this function?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am taking a course on LinkedIn Learning that is teaching me PHP and MySQL. Questions in the Q&A section don't usually get responded to so I was hoping I could find some help here.

In this course, I am making a multi-page website that accesses a MySQL DB. We have just created the DB and are now starting to build the components to connect to the DB. There is a **db_credentials.php** script that defines `DB_SERVER` `DB_USER` `DB_PASS` `DB_NAME`

Then I also have a database.php script which is here

```
<?php

    require_once('db_credentials.php');

    function db_connect() {
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        return $connection;
    }

    function db_disconnect($connection) {
        if(isset($connection)) {
            mysqli_close($connection);
        }
    }

?>
```

This all makes sense to me. I also have a script called **initialize.php** that is included in my header, therefore every page of the website. In this initialize.php script we just added the following snippet `$db = db_connect();`
Ok, that makes sense too. This way we can just put `$db` in our code instead of typing out `db_connect` (Am I right or are there other reasons why we would assign this function to this variable?)

Ok so here is the part I am struggling with. In our **footer.php** we are including code to close the DB connection if it is open so that we aren't using resources needlessly. The code in the footer is `db_disconnect($db);`
I just can't understand why we need the `$db` argument. Wouldn't we be able to close the connection by just calling the `db_disconnect` function without any arguments?

Comment: Your application could be depending on multiple database connections. If you do not pass the specific connection to `mysqli_close`, how would it know which one to close?

Comment: When you use `$db = db_connect()` you're actually assigning the variable $db to the value that the function returns (and not to the function itself).  Your function returns a database connection and so $db will contain this.

Comment: @Andy This is a huge help, thanks for explaining. I have also been starting to learn Python3. Just out of curiosity, does it behave the same way? By that I mean setting a variable for a function means that when you call that variable in your code it returns the value that the function provides, instead of calling the function itself.

Comment: @Benjamin it calls the function and the function returns a result.  You assign the variable to the value that the function returns.  Python does behave the same way.  In PHP (and other languages) you do have the concept of storing a functions in a variable but unless you're going to learn a functional language (like NodeJS or Elixir) I wouldn't complicate things with that now.  For now focus on the returned value :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that neither of these two functions serves any useful purpose. You should only ever create one instance of mysqli object in your application and there is no need to close it.

Your connection code is also incomplete. You need to enable error reporting and set the proper charset. The correct mysqli connection code should look something like this:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

Now you can include this file using `require 'db.php';` or something similar or you can use a proper dependency injection container. In a real application, you should almost never see any kind of `include`/`require`.

The function to close is completely redundant. `mysqli_close()` is already a function that closes mysqli connection, why would you ever need to wrap it into another function? Besides, as I have already said, there is no need to close the connection. PHP will close the connection for you at the end of the script.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.
This is an entry level course teaching the basics of PHP and MySQL in one course. This means that things aren't always done in the most efficient way, they are done so that we can understand a variety of ways to do things. He did mention that there is no need to close the connection, but he said it is a best practice. Is he incorrect about that? This course was made in 2017, did it handle SQL connections the same back then?
-We have the charset in our header.php. Can we omit it here then?
I don't know what a dependency injection container is yet.

Comment: It was not the best practice in 2017 also. I would say it's a bad practice to close the connection. However, mysqli has a really bad history and there are plenty of terrible tutorials If you see PHP tutorial using mysqli then you should avoid it. Look only for the ones that teach PDO. PDO has been the best API for the past ten years now. Start with https://phpdelusions.net/pdo